# pip install pymsgbox offline always failed

Tags: python, pip

I need to publish my python app on windows with offline install, but it fails when install pymsgbox:

```
c:\Users\admin\Desktop\python3\pip>pip3.6 install --no-index --find-links=.\ pymsgbox==1.0.9
```

Looking in links: .
Collecting pymsgbox==1.0.9
Installing build dependencies ... error
Complete output from command "c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gahbccbj --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links .\ -- setuptools>=38.2.5 wheel:
Looking in links: .
Collecting setuptools>=38.2.5
Collecting wheel
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for wheel

---

Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-gahbccbj --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links .\ -- setuptools>=38.2.5 wheel" failed with error code 1 in None

I have already install setuptools>=38.2.5

```
c:\Users\admin\Desktop\python3\pip>pip3.6 list | findstr setuptools
```

setuptools     42.0.2

If I install pymsgbox online, it success:

```
c:\Users\admin\Desktop\python3\pip>pip3.6 install  pymsgbox==1.0.9 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting pymsgbox==1.0.9
Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/7d/ff/4c6f31a4f08979f12a663f2aeb6c8b765d3bd592e66eaaac445f547bb875/PyMsgBox-1.0.9.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... done
Installing collected packages: pymsgbox
Running setup.py install for pymsgbox ... done
Successfully installed pymsgbox-1.0.9

Why it requires setuptools while already satisfied?

Comment: `--find-links` has to point to a directory where you have the necessary packages. `pip` is looking for the `wheel` package in the `.` directory but it cannot find it. You have to either pre-install it same as `setuptools`, or ship it along with the `pymsgbox` package.

Comment: pip3.6 install --no-index --find-links=%PIPPath% pyautogui --no-build-isolation will be ok